# Perform Background Tasks in Low Power Mode - Possible?

Tags: power, scheduled-tasks, daemon, low-power

**Is there a way to schedule low power background activities to be performed while a computer is idle, sleeping, or even powered off?**

Until recently I would have thought the answer was unconditionally "no". However I have recently learned about the Wake on LAN and Wake on WLAN protocols and I was fascinated - mostly by this bit from [the Wikipedia article about WoL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN).

> Powered-down or turned off computers capable of Wake-on-LAN will contain network devices able to "listen" to incoming packets in low-power mode while the system is powered down.

I read further on the subject, and found this excerpt from [the Carbon Copy Cloner FAQ page](https://bombich.com/kb/ccc4/frequently-asked-questions-about-scheduled-tasks).

> If your backup task is configured to "Wake or power on the system", CCC will schedule a "Wake or power on" event with the Power Management service and your system will turn on shortly before the task is scheduled to run.

so it seems like the motherboard must still be responding to scheduled instructions from the system clock even when powered off.

**I'd like to make clear that I am not an idiot and I understand there are some fundamental limitations to this kind of functionality.** I understand that the system might literally lack enough power to perform any process, and I understand that this kind of functionality will be very hardware dependent. **But I am still curious if it's at all possible to create my own low power daemon that operates in a similar way to these?**

Comment: There are 2 different technologies that you're talking about (one's wake-on-lan, the other is wake timers). In either scenario your machine will return to the normal "on" S0 power state. I guess I'm confused what you mean by "low power daemon", are you asking whether or not you can utilize these for other purposes/your own software?

Comment: @BrianC Well what I mean is that, even when the computer is off, the NIC keeps listening and the timer keeps timing. Is it possible for me to create a program/kernel extension that keeps doing something while the computer is off?

Comment: Oh. Well there is a technology in newer versions of Windows called "connected standby" / "InstantGo" / "modern standby". That's a whole different animal than you described in your original post, might want to read up on that. WoL / timers is really just a function of the motherboard / NIC / realtime clock; the OS isn't actually doing anything in that state. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: In other words, WoL / timers are returning your system to an S0 state. There is another state called S0 low power idle which isn't related to those.